# Reference Objects in sessions

Tags: c#, session-state

if a list of objects are saved in the session, the session gets updated automatically when a new object is added to the list due to objects declared as reference types.. why this is not the same case when removing an item from the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it depends on session state mode. Your thoughts would be for in-process mode or some other custom mode that would store objects in-memory.

In the other hand, removing an object from session state doesn't mean you killed it. It's just a collection of objects like any other (f.e. List).

Objects are destroyed and removed from memory by Garbage Collector.

You can read more about Garbage Collector in this MSDN article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx

Comment: I am using SQLServer mode. yes i am aware of the GC behavior .. my question is why the session is not updated (the list still contains the deleted item) while in case of add even without explicitly updating the session it gets updates

Comment: Can you re-compose your question better? It's hard to imagine what you're doing in your project... Thanks!